# How to change the color for particular character in UITextView of iphone using xcode?

Tags: iphone

How to change the color for particular character in UITextView?

Answer (score 1):

Overkill for your case but you can try this: [Three20 UI](http://three20.info/overview#UI)

Comment: +1 This is the only solution for attributed text on the iPhone at this time.

Comment: accept questions if you think they are good. It is a best thank here

Answer (score 0):

when i need formatted text - i'm using UIWebView & HTML.
maybe it is a solution?)

Answer (score 0):

You can't. The whole text will be affected. If you need rich formatting, then use UIWebView instead.

Answer (score 0):

Now you can use Nimbus Attributed Text.
I suppose Nimbus is the successor of Three20.
http://docs.nimbuskit.info/index.html